# Get top presented view controller form navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigation controller. So I can get viewControllers array from it. So the last object is view controller that has presented new view controller. Then from this new view controller I have presented another controller.

How to get the top one?

I write this code that I really don't like:

```
po [[[[[[MainViewController shared] rootNavigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] presentedViewController] presentedViewController]
```

Comment: why do you need to do this? One thing that will remove some of that code is the `[UINavigationController topViewController]` property

Comment: @quark it give me second viewcontroller from viewcontrollers list. but this second view controller already presented new view controller. and I need last presented

Comment: The question was, *why* do you need to get the top presented view controller?

Comment: Try the navigation controller's `visibleViewController` property.